# Why does PHP AJAX work as from second click only?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

New to PHP and AJAX.

I made a basic page whereby when I click a button, a php page will connect to a database and return me the name of the person whose age is 45 (already included in the url when sending).

My only issue is, it works only as from the second time I click the button. Help please?

My code for ajax.html and ajax-example.php below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        function ajaxFunction() {
            ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = reaction();
            ajaxRequest.open("GET","ajax-example.php?age=45", true);
            ajaxRequest.send(null);
        }

        function reaction() {
            if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
               alert(ajaxRequest.responseText);
            }
        }
     </script>

      <button onclick="ajaxFunction();">Click me</button>

   </body>
</html>

<?php
   $server = "localhost";
   $user = "root";
   $password = "";
   $db = "ajaxtrial";

  $conn = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$password,$db);

  if (!$conn) {
      die('Failure to connect!');
  }

  $age = $_GET['age'];

  $sql = "SELECT name FROM ajax_example WHERE age =".$age;

  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $display = "The name is ".$row['name'];
  }

  echo $display;
?>
```

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? Have you opened the browser's developer tools to see if you have any errors?

Comment: Only one, after I closed the alert box. It said Violation 'click' handler took 1205 ms

Comment: Remove the parentheses when assigning `reaction` to `onreadystatechange` event. Currently `reaction` is executed immediately, it should wait untill the event fires.

Comment: And it was as simple as that! I feel dumb lol. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the parenthesis for the `reaction` method that you are assigning to `onreadystatechange`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    function ajaxFunction() {
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = reaction;
        ajaxRequest.open("GET","ajax-example.php?age=45", true);
        ajaxRequest.send(null);
    }

    function reaction() {
        if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
           alert(ajaxRequest.responseText);
        }
    }
 </script>
```

OR you can initialize an anonymous function to `onreadystatechange`.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    function ajaxFunction() {
        ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
           if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status == 200) {
               alert(ajaxRequest.responseText);
           }
        }
        ajaxRequest.open("GET","ajax-example.php?age=45", true);
        ajaxRequest.send(null);
    }
 </script>
```

I hope that helps you.

Comment: By looking at the comments, I can know that you have already got the answer. But I feel my answer may help others in the community.